# Steam through WINE; nothing happens after login

Tags: wine, steam

I have ubuntu 13.10 installed and I'm still very new to this. I'm still trying to grasp the system mechanics so I would like a step by step solution.

I've downloaded and installed wine 1.5 with winetricks. Using winetricks I installed Steam successfully. When I run Steam the login screen comes up fine. The problem appears after typing in my info and logging in. It just closes, with nothing appearing.

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Garrison please see the question marked as duplicate. It covers steam, configuring wine correctly (even using an updated wine version) and solving general problems.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Could you please explain how this is a duplicate of the "question" you selected? While your answer there is a nice overview that everybody with problems should have read, it is very general and does not really treat Steam in detail (just as an example and assuming everything works fine). This question here is instead very specific and should not be closed as a duplicate just because there is a general question about wine. Yes the answers here are general and covered in your answer, but the question is not. In my opinion the question should stay open.

Comment: i marked the question as duplicate because of the relationship between using steam through wine and the actual problem with steam (again, in wine). my answer covers where to actually look for solutions related to any wine app and how to solve most of the problems related to them. if the case were that steam was used natively in linux as recommended by vale, steam and ubuntu, then the first link i provide in the answer points to the how to guide for steam related installations. will continue on the comment below...

Comment: the fact is, the main reason the how to guide for wine was created is because there were hundreds of questions that mentioned some kind of issue with installing an app in wine. the question tries to address most of this issues and even extends to some very specific ones but gives the reader an almost complete guide on how to solve most wine problems, specific or not to 1 app. not only this but the amount of steam and wine related questions is pretty big already. if the guide does not help with an answer there probably will already exist one.

Comment: with this in mind, i do not have a problem with reopening the question if the op and other readers that need a similar answer do not find what they need on the guide or links inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can download Steam .deb from it's site http://store.steampowered.com/

Comment: I'm trying to download the windows installer for steam, so that I'm able to play some steam games that aren't supported by linux. That's why I'm running it through Wine.

Answer (score 1):

not an actual answer (it would not let me post a comment to first post), but some info:

same happens on Debian, wine 1.6 from sid, official Steam instaler (.msi)

It installs fine, it opens fine, I log in, and then... it closes without any kind of message.

this is the console log: http://pastie.org/8530710

PS: almost same (crash after login) with steam 1.4 from stable. I thought updating to 1.6 would fix it, but it seems it doesn't.

PPS: a quite actual answer: **updating to latest (wine) GIT release could help** (I saw that on winehq regarding last Steam update, or something.... ). but I'm too lazy to compile a 32 bit package on a 64 bit machine, only to find it still not working....

***EDIT:*** http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35030
it IS a bug, and it has been resolved in last git release. now, if anyone wants to update...

oh, and btw, the bug is present in ALL recent (stable) versions of wine (1.4 ; 1.5 and 1.6) (wine 1.7.X is still in devel)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Wine 1.6. 
As far as I know, usually when somebody have any problem with Wine installing new version is one of the firsts things suggested.

---

Ok, I checked it on my Wine 1.6 and same problem appeared. I guess it's Steam's problem because before it run without any problem.

---

Isn't it a problem like Yours: http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/666825524990131434/ ?

---

Now, after installing Wine 1.7, Steam works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) instead of plain wine.

There you can just choose to install Steam from a menu. It will download the client, install it and install a lot of small extensions (selected stuff from winetricks, missing libraries, etc.) known to be needed by Steam. Maybe it works this way.

This also allows you to keep different programs in separate wine prefixes (think of it as separate windows installations within wine), which can prevent different programs interfering with one another.

Furthermore it allows to choose the wine version without much effort. You do not have to use the newest version, when an older one is reported to work better for some reason.